# Hibernate Distributed Cache - can multiple applications share same cache?

Tags: hibernate

I'm looking to setup Hibernate with distributed cache where I have one application writing to the DB and another one reading from the DB. Is there an easy way to notify the reading application when the writing one has written through Hibernate? The distributed cache will invalidate the cache but I need the reading application to know a change has been made to refresh its data immediately.

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a replicating cache such as JBossCache,InfiniSpan or EHCache and configure to replicate updates instead of invalidating cache.
e.g.
http://docs.jboss.org/jbosscache/1.4.0/TreeCache/en/html/replication.html
http://ehcache.org/documentation/distributed_caching.html

Comment: Dead link pls provide details in your answer. Link only answers do not survive well over time.

Answer (score 3):

You're not going to get this working without some effort, I think, although all of the components are there to do the individual bits you need.

Specifically, Hibernate has built-in support for [JBossCache 2](http://jboss.org/jbosscache) as a [2nd-level distributed cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-cache). JBossCache *does* provide an event architecture which allows you to listen to changes in the cache.

The challenge will be to tie the two together, and figure out how to listen to changes in the JBossCache config that hibernate uses. It should be possible, you'll just have to do a bit of reading.

JBossCache2 is a bit old now, but it's the latest version that Hibernate supports out-of-the-box. There is documentation on the JBossCache website for getting v3 working with Hibernate, but that takes extra work.

Edit: It seems that development of JBossCache is being halted in favour of its replacement, [Infinispan](http://www.jboss.org/infinispan). There's documentation on how to [integrate that with Hibernate](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/usinginfinispanasjpahibernatesecondlevelcacheprovider).

Comment: Thanks for your reply but not sure about your answer. I did some research and I think I need to simply use a replicating cache. (EHCache, Infinispan, JBossCache all provide implementations of replicating cache which work out of the box with Hibernate). The difference between a replicating cache and a distributed cache being that an add/update/delete in replicating cache will update all nodes, where as in a regular distrbitued cache it will just invalidate. http://docs.jboss.org/jbosscache/1.4.0/TreeCache/en/html/replication.html

Comment: @DD: Don't get too distracted by terminology, and what you think replicated/distributed means. All of the above technologies will do any of the things you mention.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.,,You dont appear need to use an event architecture to do this. Replicating cache solutions do this out of the box. So when you say its a challenge to tie the two together thats doesnt appear to be the case. Sounds fairly straightforward but I still have to try it :-) http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache